# handling 2 recursive calls simultaneously

Tags: python, recursion, quicksort

When I make 2 recursive calls within the same function, like for example when implementing quicksort, the first recursive call is always handled before the second call. Is there some way to handle both recursive calls simultaneously rather than consecutively? This would also mean that the list being sorted is being modified simultaneously. I'm currently using python

Comment: Could you please provide us with: a use case, the code, expected input/output? There might be a much better way to do this...

Comment: The program could create two threads for the two recursive calls, but eventually you will reach the limit on the number of threads that can run at the same time, depending on the number of hyperthreading cores on your system. At some number of threads, the sorting will become memory bandwidth limited.

Comment: @rcgldr i didnt know what multithreading was until like yesterday lol

Answer (score 0):

"This would also mean that the list being sorted is being modified simultaneously."

don't do that

Build a new list as you go.